# SQL Case - grouping values returned by ELSE

Tags: sql

[image: This is my case expression:]

[image: These are my results:]

How can I receive only one row for category "Other" with a total of 111?

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: You should post your entire query, as formatted text, not picture. Also tag your dbms (as the `sql` tag asked you to).

Comment: And how does  `GROUP BY` clause look? Please post entire query as text. I guess that it is MySQL and GROUP BY in not aligned with SELECT

Comment: Sounds like a sub-query / common table expression would do the trick

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Use `COUNT(Channel)` instead.

Comment: SELECT CASE HHHOGCL --Originating Source of Order
   WHEN 'P' THEN 'One Step'
   WHEN 'O' THEN 'Customer Service'
      WHEN 'R' THEN 'Remote FTP'
      WHEN 'N' THEN 'PowerNet'
      WHEN 'S' THEN 'PowerSell'
      WHEN 'M' THEN 'PowerMobile'
      ELSE 'Other'
       END AS "Channel", COUNT(HHHOGCL) AS "Orders per Channel"
              
FROM S2151BDW.PWRDTA.FFDCSTBP 
JOIN S2151BDW.PWRDTA.HHHORDHL0 ON HHHCUSN = FFDCUSN  
    
WHERE HHHCMPN = 1 AND HHHDIVN = 1 AND HHHDPTN = 1

AND
HHHDTES > 0 --Ship Date

AND
HHHDTES BETWEEN 20180611 AND 20180611

GROUP BY HHHOGCL

Comment: Do **NOT** post code in comments [edit] your question

Answer (score 1):

You should GROUP BY  CASE expression instead of `HHHOGCL`:

```
SELECT CASE hhhogcl
                  WHEN 'P' THEN 'One Step'
                  WHEN 'O' THEN 'Customer Service'
                  WHEN 'R' THEN 'Remote FTP'
                  WHEN 'N' THEN 'PowerNet'
                  WHEN 'S' THEN 'PowerSell'
                  WHEN 'M' THEN 'PowerMobile'
                  ELSE 'Other'
         END            AS "Channel",
         Count(*) AS "Orders per Channel"
FROM     s2151bdw.pwrdta.ffdcstbp
JOIN     s2151bdw.pwrdta.hhhordhl0
ON       hhhcusn = ffdcusn
WHERE    hhhcmpn = 1
AND      hhhdivn = 1
AND      hhhdptn = 1
AND      hhhdtes > 0 --Ship Date AND HHHDTES BETWEEN 20180611 AND 20180611
GROUP BY
         CASE hhhogcl
                  WHEN 'P' THEN 'One Step'
                  WHEN 'O' THEN 'Customer Service'
                  WHEN 'R' THEN 'Remote FTP'
                  WHEN 'N' THEN 'PowerNet'
                  WHEN 'S' THEN 'PowerSell'
                  WHEN 'M' THEN 'PowerMobile'
                  ELSE 'Other'
         END
```

Comment: I see, that worked perfectly, thank you for your help.

Comment: How would I change NULL to "Total" in my output?

Comment: @DanB. Sorry but I do not understand. There is no `NULL` value in your output. Maybe you mean `COUNT(*)`? If not please post desired resultset.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `CASE` query up in a derived table, `GROUP BY` its result.

```
select "Channel", count(*) AS "Orders per Channel"
from
(
    SELECT CASE hhhogcl
                      WHEN 'P' THEN 'One Step'
                      WHEN 'O' THEN 'Customer Service'
                      WHEN 'R' THEN 'Remote FTP'
                      WHEN 'N' THEN 'PowerNet'
                      WHEN 'S' THEN 'PowerSell'
                      WHEN 'M' THEN 'PowerMobile'
                      ELSE 'Other'
             END            AS "Channel",
    FROM     s2151bdw.pwrdta.ffdcstbp
    JOIN     s2151bdw.pwrdta.hhhordhl0
    ON       hhhcusn = ffdcusn
    WHERE    hhhcmpn = 1
    AND      hhhdivn = 1
    AND      hhhdptn = 1
    AND      hhhdtes > 0 --Ship Date AND HHHDTES BETWEEN 20180611 AND 20180611
) dt
GROUP BY "Channel"
```

ANSI SQL compliant!